# angular 5: Get nested FormControl element reference

Tags: angular, angular5

I would need to write following line of code to access nested form control in the template and this is causing the problem in my template files because this is a big string.

```
this.fromGroupName.controls[i].controls[i]controls.maxPersonCount.valid
```

Could we have some direct method over fromGroupName to get nested form control reference?

Comment: whats your problem ?

Comment: when I need to show errors in the template file, I need to use multiple such conditions in the *ngIf and that is making ngIf untrackable.

Comment: is it showing any error add your template to your question

Comment: I'd prefer to use `get`: `formName.get('a.b.c').valid`... Or if you want to check if there are errors: `formName.hasError('errorCode', 'a.b.c')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) so you break out your nested form into their components. check out this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-patch-ksjfpt?file=app%2Fquantity-list.component.ts) to get an idea

OR

Create functions in your component.ts file that access individual controls  and use those functions in your template file. check out this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-patch-bjrpe5?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) 
and you will see a function in my *component.ts file

```
quantitiesFormArray(index) {
 return (this.form.get('ingredients') as FormArray).controls[index].get('quantities');
}
```

and in my template I use like so

```
quantitiesFormArray(i).hasError('exceededApprovedQuantity')
```